# How to create the round/rectangle dialog on GIMP or Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, shapes

How do you design that bubble?:

[image]

I tried to use a rectangle and a rounded shape but didn't work out nicely. Would be really nice if someone can point out (or if this kind of shape already exist!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Photoshop I'd draw a `Round Corners Rectangle`, and then use the `Direct Selection Tool` to  eliminate the curves of the corner you want in a straight angle:

[image]

I think there is a tool in Gimp that lets you give each corner of the round rectangle a different value, but I'm not sure.

Comment: point out that the rectangle tool is right next to the pen tool and that you can adjust the corner radius in the tool's options bar